# Linux POSIX C dynamic string array issue

Tags: c, arrays, posix

I have the following code, it searches for some matches with regex (pcre) then adds the matches to a dynamically growing array (so I can make the matches unique)... the problem I get two warnings when compiling and when running the program crashes.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pcre.h>

int main() {
  pcre *myregexp;
  const char *error;
  int erroroffset;
  int offsetcount;
  int offsets[(0+1)*3]; // (max_capturing_groups+1)*3
  const char *result;
  int n;
  int count = 1;
  char **matches;
  char **more_matches;
  char *subject = "9,5,3,2,5,6,3,2,5,6,3,2,2,2,5,0,5,5,6,6,1,";
  myregexp = pcre_compile("\\d,", PCRE_MULTILINE|PCRE_DOTALL, &error, &erroroffset, NULL);

  if (myregexp != NULL) {
    offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), 0, 0, offsets, (0+1)*3);

    while (offsetcount > 0) {

      if (pcre_get_substring(subject, offsets, offsetcount, 0, &result) >= 0) {
        printf("%s\n", result);
        more_matches = (char *) realloc(matches, count * sizeof(char));
        if (more_matches!=NULL) {
          matches=more_matches;
          matches[count-1]=result;
          count++;
        }
        else {
          free(matches);
          puts("Error (re)allocating memory");
          exit(1);
       }
      }

      offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), offsets[1], 0, offsets, (0+1)*3);
    }
    for (n=0; n<count; n++) printf("%s\n", matches[n]);
    free(matches);
  } else {
      printf("Syntax error in REGEX at erroroffset\n");
  }

}
```

casting something wrong?

```
$ gcc -o pcre_ex_arr pcre_ex_arr.c -lpcre
pcre_ex_arr.c: In function 'main':
pcre_ex_arr.c:29: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
pcre_ex_arr.c:32: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
$ ./pcre_ex_arr
2,
*** glibc detected *** ./pcre_ex_arr: realloc(): invalid pointer: 0xb7fcfb80 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
```

Comment: For one thing, this: `sizeof(char)` in your realloc should be `sizeof(char*)`, and the types aren't comparable (assigning a `const char*` to a `char*`), but thats a different issue. (i.e. `matches` is the wrong type). You also never initialize `matches` to NULL before starting this thing up, which is critical for the first iteration to work.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Let me retry.

Comment: `char **matches = NULL;` and `char **more_matches = NULL;` now the code works, but I get the same warnings when finishing it segfaults. And by the way, `printf` outputs data twice.

Comment: sorry, deleted your last post, oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of things wrong:

1. Using the wrong `sizeof()` when resizing your `matches` pointer array
2. Failing to initialize `matches` to NULL before the parsing begins.
3. Using the wrong type for the `matches` and `more_matches` pointers.
4. Using a volatile pointer to read-only memory for `subject`
5. Casting `malloc` and `realloc` is never good in C
6. The math on your `count` is flaky-at-best. It should start at 0, not 1

See below:

```
int main()
{
    pcre *myregexp;
    const char *error;
    int erroroffset;
    int offsetcount;
    int offsets[(0+1)*3]; // (max_capturing_groups+1)*3
    const char *result;
    int n;
    int count = 0;
    const char **matches = NULL;
    const char **more_matches;

    char subject[] = "9,5,3,2,5,6,3,2,5,6,3,2,2,2,5,0,5,5,6,6,1,";
    myregexp = pcre_compile("\\d,", PCRE_MULTILINE|PCRE_DOTALL, &error, &erroroffset, NULL);

    if (myregexp != NULL) {
        offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), 0, 0, offsets, (0+1)*3);

        while (offsetcount > 0) {

            if (pcre_get_substring(subject, offsets, offsetcount, 0, &result) >= 0)
            {
                printf("%s\n", result);
                more_matches = realloc(matches, (count+1)* sizeof(*more_matches));
                if (more_matches!=NULL)
                {
                    matches=more_matches;
                    matches[count++]=result;
                }
                else
                {
                    free(matches);
                    puts("Error (re)allocating memory");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }

            offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), offsets[1], 0, offsets, (0+1)*3);
        }

        for (n=0; n<count; n++) printf("%s\n", matches[n]);
        free(matches);

    } else {
        printf("Syntax error in REGEX at erroroffset\n");
    }
}
```